# Is there any benefit to use wp_localize_script to pass php value to js for ajax call in wordpress?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

Codex says we need to use `wp_localize_script` to pass php value to external js file, like the code below:

```
function bangla_load_scripts($hook){

    global $add_settings;
    if ($hook =! $add_settings) {
        return;
    }

wp_enqueue_script('bangla-ajax', plugin_dir_url(__FILE__).'js/bangla-ajax.js', array('jquery')  );
wp_localize_script( 'bangla-ajax', 'ajax_object',
            array( 'ajax_url' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ), 'we_value' => 1234 );

}
add_action('admin_enqueue_scripts', 'bangla_load_scripts');
```

and the file js/bangla-ajax.js is as below:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
  $('#bangla-ajax-form').click(function(){   
    data = {
      'action' : 'bangla_get_results',
      'val1'   : ajax_object.we_value
    }       
    $.post(ajax_object.ajax_url, data, function(response){
         alert(response);
    });
    return false;
  });
});
```

But can't we just simply use `'val1' : $('#selectorid').val()`
so that we don't need to use `wp_localize_script` and all these extra codes, associated with it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you read the documentation it outlines that you might want to use this method if you are internationalizing your code and require JS variables from PHP that may need to be translated.

From what I gather, besides internationalization it is also a method of keeping your PHP and JS code slightly more seperated than having a mess of PHP variable injections in the middle of your JS code.

As far as your example goes, it's somewhat hard to follow as you don't outline your use-case at all, but from what I gather, if you are just pulling data out of a form element to post it to your ajax endpoint then wp_localize_script isn't even relevant to what you are doing.

Comment: hey, thanks for the clarification,  i actually need to pass an input value of a form field. How do i do that? In my example i used 'we_value' => 1234, but i want to replace 1234 with the input value.

Comment: Then your use-case for wp_localize_script is fine.